# Sorting object keys in javascript based on value

Tags: javascript, object

I am receiving weird response from 3rd party api , that looks like below

```
{
  "27000CE": -1,
  "27100CE": 2,
  "27300CE": -1,
  "27200CE": 5
}
```

How do I sort this by value ?

like ascending or descending.

```
{
  "27300CE": -1,
  "27000CE": -1,
  "27100CE": 2,
  "27200CE": 5
}
```

I tried something like below

```
sortArrayOfObjects = (arr, key) => {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
        return a[key] - b[key];
    });
};
```

But all keys are different and thats the problem.

Comment: yea type of this seems to be like object ,, but thats the response i receive by api

Comment: Is this a text response? Like, is the API sending this exact string of characters? If so, the first order of business is to manually parse it into an actual array / object.

Comment: hi , i edited my question , please remove the downvote , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the **[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)** and then create a new object using **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** like this:

```js
const response = {
  "27100CE": 2,
  "27000CE": -1,
  "27300CE": -1,
  "27200CE": 5
}

const sorted = Object.entries(response)
                         .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
                         .reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
                            r[key] = value
                            return r
                         }, {})

console.log(sorted)
```

This works only if you don't have any integer keys in `response`. More info: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you receive an object, in that case your input will be like this:

```
let obj = {"27300CE": -1, "27200CE": 5, "27100CE": 2, "27000CE": -1}
```

And you can sort by values like so:

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj);

// Then sort by using the keys to lookup the values in the original object:
keys.sort(function(a, b) { return obj[a] - obj[b] });

console.log(keys);//["27300CE", "27000CE", "27100CE", "27200CE"]
```

based upon new keys sequence you can create a new obj , sorted one if you like

Comment: hi , this sorts only key , i need it with value too

Comment: yeah well, you can use it to generate a new sorted obj, i didnt know it was a big of a deal